# How to send the values of a php array of classes from a php file to another php file

Tags: php, html

i have an array of classes in a php file, this class has 3 fields, and i am using these fields to save the values of SELECTS and INPUT CHECKBOXs inside a FORM using POST, then i need to send this array of classes to another php file for proccessing data.

```
<?php 
   class info_subject{

   public $code_as;
   public $time_as;
   public $selectionn_as;

       }

  $subjects[0] = new info_subject();//The only way I have seen for creating an array of classes
  //is with a for loop, but if you have a better way for doing this, please let me know       
  $subjects[1] = new info_subject();

  //here  i am using the fields to save info in a form

 $i=0;
 echo "<form name = 'formsubjects' method='post' action='file2.php'>";
 echo "<select name=\"".$subjects[$i]->time_as ."\">";
 //options
 echo "</select>";
 echo "<input type='checkbox' name=\"".$asignaturas[$i]->selection_as."\">";
 //and so on with every position of the array using $i
 ?>

 //then there is a button to send the the dato to file2.php

 //file2.php
 <?php

 $subjects=$_POST["$subjects"];//I am using this but i cant retrieve the fields of $subjects

   ?>
```

What can i do buddies?

Comment: You should definitely take a look at the MVC architecture.

Comment: Whats that buddy?...

Comment: A way of programming that would not let you mix HTML with PHP the way you did, that said, it doesn't solve your problem.For your problem I would suggest you to create a method that return the variables you need, you would then use your class in your other file and call the function you've just implemented

Comment: you have a spelling mistake: $asignaturas[$i]->selection_as should probably be: $subject[$i]->selection_as

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of:

```
$i=0;
echo "<form name = 'formsubjects' method='post' action='file2.php'>";
echo "<select name=\"".$subjects[$i]->time_as ."\">";
//options
echo "</select>";
echo "<input type='checkbox' name=\"".$asignaturas[$i]->selection_as."\">";
```

you can try something like:

```
$i=0;
echo "<form name = 'formsubjects' method='post' action='file2.php'>";
echo "<select name=\"subjects[$i][".$subjects[$i]->time_as ."]\">";
//options
echo "</select>";
echo "<input type='checkbox' name=\"subjects[$i][".$asignaturas[$i]->selection_as."]\">";
```

and then in file2

```
$subjects=$_POST["subjects"];
```

and pick off what you need.

To be honest, I find your question hard to understand.  Maybe try streamlining your problem and clean up some code/formatting and it will be easier for us to give you advice.

Answer (score 0):

You can't submit a class or array via $_POST because the post array is an array which can only contain simple values.

Answer (score 0):

Hi~ Jose Ricardo Citerio. I hope you can read Chinese

我不知道你是不是需要这样，在file1里面存储着select的option选项。然后file2接收去后处理

```
<?php
```

class info_subject{

```
public $code_as = ['name' => 'select_name', 'option' => ["k" => "v"]];
public $time_as;
public $selectionn_as;
```

}

$subjects = new info_subject();

echo "";
echo 'code_as["name"] . '">"';
//loop options for $subjects["option"] and print k and v; like => foreach($subjects->code_as["name"] as $k => $v){echo '' . $v . '';}
echo "";
echo 'xxx['name'] . '">please check';

?>

//then there is a button to send the the dato to file2.php

//file2.php

```
<?php
$subjects = $_POST["select_name"];
$subjects1 = $_POST["checkbox_name"];
```

?>